# SetWindowTheme - how to prevent visual styles from being applied to a window?

Tags: c++, windows

I read this Microsoft documentation about SetWindowTheme: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827(v=vs.85).aspx and it says:

> When pszSubAppName and pszSubIdList are NULL, the theme manager removes the previously applied associations. You can prevent visual styles from being applied to a specified window by specifying an empty string, (L" "), which does not match any section entries.

The `L" "` above does not look like an empty string to me though - it has a space in it. Should I pass in `L""` or `L" "` to prevent visual styles from being applied?

Here is the usage of it I'm working with. The c-style cast from char* to WCHAR* looks dubious to me:

```
// obtain function pointer to SetWindowTheme
(FARPROC&)SetWindowTheme = ::GetProcAddress(dll, "SetWindowTheme"); 
if (SetWindowTheme != 0) {
    WCHAR *empty = (WCHAR*)" "; 
    (*SetWindowTheme)( hWnd, empty, empty );
}
```

Comment: *Everything* is dubious, use `#include <uxtheme.h>` to get somewhere.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? In VS 2015 and higher you can use `SetWindowTheme` right away after include files.